# Reading file in python without linebreak

Tags: python

I want to be able to read a file and add a string onto it line by line without having a line break in the middle.

```
text_file = open("read_it.txt", "r")
print text_file.readline() + "0123456789"
```

Outputs to

```
>>
text
0123456789
>>
```

I would like have it output to this format

```
>>
text0123456789
>>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [rstrip](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.rstrip) method:

```
text_file.readline().rstrip() + "0123456789"
```

Comment: +1, but be aware that not only (CR)LF but also other whitespace will be stripped off the end of the line.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Of course you are right. But you can use `text.rstrip("\r\n")` instead to only strip newlines.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right. Sorry about that. Well, you already have my +1 (but still, `\n` is enough, even on Windows).

Comment: How about text.rstrip(os.linesep) ?